# MySQL multiple index columns have a full cardinality?

Tags: mysql, index-tuning

I have noticed indexes like:

```
+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table             | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| archive_city_item |          1 | ARCHIVE_CITY_ITEM_IDX |            1 | city_id        | A         |        7851 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| archive_city_item |          1 | ARCHIVE_CITY_ITEM_IDX |            2 | item_id        | A         |      266502 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| archive_city_item |          1 | ARCHIVE_CITY_ITEM_IDX |            3 | vote_date      | A         |     4530535 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| archive_city_item |          1 | ARCHIVE_CITY_ITEM_IDX |            4 | ip_address_str | A         |     4530535 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| archive_city_item |          1 | ARCHIVE_CITY_ITEM_IDX |            5 | month          | A         |     4530535 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| archive_city_item |          1 | ARCHIVE_CITY_ITEM_IDX |            6 | year           | A         |     4530535 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
```

I guess since column 3-6 have a full cardinality this index is not goodly constructed, that it shall be deleted and the new indexes should be built (queries should be analyzed to see if it's (city_id, item_id) or maybe (city_id, item_id, votedate) or some other combination starting with (city_id, item_id...) ?

Correct? Or I'm getting this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As @Johnakahot2use mentioned, indexes on fields with really low uniqueness (low cardinality) is not a bad thing. It's just fields with high uniqueness are generally more efficient when indexed and stored in a B-Tree.

That being said, you don't normally write queries around the cardinality of the fields in your table (usually that's not even a luxury), you write queries for the data that's needed to complete the objective at hand, and you try to index (and design your schema) in a way that offers best performance to those use cases.

In other words, if one of your use cases is to get all `ip_address_str` in a specific `month` and `year`, then it makes sense to create an index on `month` and `year` (in the order of which ever field is more unique). If your use case will always require filtering on `item_id` then adding that to the index would certainly help it to be more performant but it's not a requirement for the index to be of help either.

In conclusion, create indexes and design the schema appropriate for your common use cases, not the queries around your data's cardinality (unless it so happens that works for your use cases).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `INDEX(city_id, item_id, vote_date, ip_address_str, month, year)`

**Important:** An index is used from left to right.

```
WHERE city_id = 123 AND ...   -- At least the first column of the index is used
WHERE city_id < 123 AND ...   -- ONLY the first column of the index is used
WHERE /* city_id not used */  -- The index is useless.

WHERE ... AND city_id = 123 AND ...  -- Order of ANDs does not impact index usefulness
WHERE (cidy_id = 123 OR item_id = 55) -- 'OR' destroys usefulness of any index
```

The cardinality numbers indicate that the combination of city_id + item_id + vote_date is *estimated* to be unique.  Having the rest of the columns in the index probably does not add much, if anything.

**6 columns?**

For selectivity, the first 3 columns seem sufficient.  However, if the data is not evenly distributed, there may be cases where more columns are useful.

For "covering", having 6 columns may be wise.

But...  Note that if a query needs only the first N columns, your 6-column index could still be useful.  That is, if you have `INDEX(a,b,c,d)`, there is no need to *also* `have INDEX(a,b)`.  On the other hand, if the longer one is not really useful for *any* query, then shorten it.  `INDEX(a,c)` is only partially helped by that longer index; it may be valid to add it.

**Less performant exceptions**

There is a concept of a "covering" index.  This is where *all* the columns mentioned *anywhere* in the `SELECT` are included in the one `INDEX` in *any* order.  That is, the following can use your 6-column index, *in spite* of the ordering of the columns.  It will not be very efficient, but it helps *some*.  Example:

```
SELECT item_id FROM t WHERE vote_date > '2020-01-01' GROUP BY month;
```

When you run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` "covering" is indicated by "Using index" in the Extra column.

**Other**

If `month` and `year` are derived from `vote_date`, then that redundancy is possibly the 'wrong' way to design the table.  Show us the main query to discuss further.